# Crossfading Images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating an image 'slider' to embellish a landing page on a site. I created a successful, functional slider, though hope to push this further...

I'm hoping to add in an element that creates crossfading images on click (once a tile is selected from beneath the main image space), such as is detailed on the site [here](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/) (beneath *Demo 6 -Fading between multiple images on click*)

I have tried integrating the code on this site into the pre-existing JS I have added (within the HTML), though it appears to interfere with the existing elements. The JSFiddle for the current code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/BTC_eLearning/pt5bLxv2/5/).

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.main-slide {
 height: 250px;
 width: 750px;
 margin: auto;
}

.selection-panel {
 opacity: 0.6;
 filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}

.selection-panel:hover {
 opacity:1.0;
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

.selection-panel-off {
 opacity: 1.0;
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

.margins {
 margin-top: 16px!important;
 margin-bottom: 16px!important;
}

.image-spacing,.image-spacing>.single-col {
 padding: 0 8px;
}

.single-col {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}

.single-col.third {
 width: 33.33333%;
}

.image-spacing::after,.image-spacing::before {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Homepage Baner Module</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="formatting.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<style>
.mySlides {display:none}
.demo {cursor:pointer}
</style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="main-image" style="max-width:750px">
     <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/750x250/ff5100/fff" height="250px" width="100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/750x250/00ff51/fff" height="250px" width="100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/750x250/0055ff/fff" height="250px" width="100%">
 
     <div class="margins image-spacing">
         <div class="single-col third">
            <img class="demo selection-panel" src="https://dummyimage.com/750x250/ff5100/fff" style="width:100%" onclick="currentDiv(1)">
            </div>
            <div class="single-col third">
            <img class="demo selection-panel" src="https://dummyimage.com/750x250/00ff51/fff" style="width:100%" onclick="currentDiv(2)">
            </div>
            <div class="single-col third">
            <img class="demo selection-panel" src="https://dummyimage.com/750x250/0055ff/fff" style="width:100%" onclick="currentDiv(3)">
            </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" selection-panel-off", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " selection-panel-off";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do this. This example assumes your images will all fit in the same size container nicely. If not, you may want to switch to background images. First, we'll put all the .mySlides in their own container element:

```
<div class="slides-container"> 
    <img class="mySlides initopacity" src="https://dummyimage.com/750x250/ff5100/fff" height="250px" width="100%">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/750x250/00ff51/fff" height="250px" width="100%">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/750x250/0055ff/fff" height="250px" width="100%">
 </div>
```

Then we'll position those slides absolutely, relative to the container:

```
.slides-container{
  width: 750px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mySlides {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

This way, they're all on top of each other. Now, you'll notice, they all have the opacity of 0, but the first .mySlide element has a class called .initopacity. That one we'll keep visible on load:

```
.initopacity {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Now, all we need is a way to change the opacity on each slide upon click. We'll use some transitions for that:

```
.fadeout {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

.fadein {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

So now, our showDivs function just adds and removes classes, instead of changing the display properties:

```
function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  /*    x[i].style.display = "none"; */
    x[0].classList.remove('initopacity');
    x[i].classList.remove('fadein');
    x[i].classList.add('fadeout');
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" selection-panel-off", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].classList.remove('fadeout')
  x[slideIndex-1].classList.add('fadein')
  /* x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; */
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " selection-panel-off";
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pt5bLxv2/87/

Comment: This is perfect, but I am finding that I am unable to link each slide image (.mySlides) using the standard 'a href' tag.  Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: The issue is that the .myslides images are absolutely positioned. This code will probably need to be refactored a good bit to make it work with links.